# how to get the document details according to the field value in mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection named users

`var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
age: Number,
points: {type: Number, default: 0}
})`

all users have some different points like 5, 10, 20, 50
so i want to count the number of users having 5 points, 10 points etc, and want to show the counted users details also, like who are those users which are having 5 points, 10 points etc.

how to write query for that in $aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You can write a group stage and push all the values you need using the $push operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$points",
      "details": {
        "$push": {
          "name": "$name",
          "age": "$age"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In the above example, I've grouped according to points and for each group, you'll get an array containing the name and age of the people having those points

Comment: Hey thanks buddy it works, i wast just confused with the syntax now i got it thank you so much

Comment: Hey and also i need to group by the no. of users which are between 5 points to 10 and between 10 to 50 like that..?